# Creating a List in prolog recursively

Tags: prolog

i would like to create a list in prolog where in each recursive step i add an element to the list.My code:

```
solve(N,List):-
 N>5,
 solve(N-1,[a|List]),
 N<5,
 solve(N-1,[b|List]),
 N is 0.
```

This supposedly runs recursions adding a or b to the List depending on N.However this `[a|List]` does not add an element in each recursion.What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You basically need to write three clauses. First, the clause for `N = 0`.

```
solve(0, []).
```

When `N` is less than (or equal to) 5, you want to add `b` to the list. You also need to check that N is not negative, otherwise your program will recurse at infinity. You also need to calculate `N - 1` with the `is` predicate.

```
solve(N, [b | L]) :-
    N >= 0,
    N =< 5,
    M is N - 1,
    solve(M, L).
```

The third clause is for the case where `N` is greater than `5`, where `a` is added to the list.

```
solve(N, [a | L]) :-
    N > 5,
    M is N - 1,
    solve(M, L).
```

Querying for `solve(2, L)` and `solve(7, L)` yields respectively:

```
L = [b, b]                 % N = 2
L = [a, a, b, b, b, b, b]  % N = 7
```

Answer (score -1):

I assume you are trying to do this:

```
   solve(0, []).

   solve(N, [a|List]):-
       N > 5,
       solve(N-1,List).

   solve(N, [b|List]):-
       N =< 5,
       solve(N-1,List).
```